# How can I order a QuerySet in Django by a charfield with numbers?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want to order a QuerySet by a charfield with numbers in it.
I have this code:

```
MyTable.objects.all().order_by('my_char_field')
```

There are some examples of "my_char_field":

```
"ver3", "ver10", "x5.1 (1)", "ver4", "x5.1 (2)"
```

The result of the order with the code above is:

```
"ver10", "ver3", "ver4", "x5.1 (1)", "x5.1 (2)"
```

But the order that I want is:

```
"ver3", "ver4", "ver10", "x5.1 (1)", "x5.1 (2)"
```

How can I get the natural order?

Comment: Does it always start with `ver`?

Comment: Are these the only variations? Will this char field always end with series of digits and start with series of alphabets? Could the version have a dot inside e.g. `ver 2.1.2`?

Comment: @AKS The version could have a dot inside, and different starts and ends

Comment: Please update your question with a full example. its hard to guess what possible options it could have. I'm not even sure its possible to do this on a query side

Comment: Could you mention all possible configuration it has or it could have and what will be your preferred expected order for those cases in the post?

Comment: @AKS Updated with all possible combinations

Comment: I agree with @Sayse. Looking at the possible options I don't think we could do it on the query side. Could you try getting the expected order with SQL only in db-shell?

Comment: @AKS, I can use loops or any function to achieve this, but the source is the QuerySet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems more like a data storage issue. It becomes *much* easier if you change your data structure

```
version_type = models.CharField()
version_num = models.FloatField()
version_revision = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True)

unique_together = [('version_type', 'version_num', 'version_revision')]

.order_by('version_type', 'version_num', 'version_revision')
```

This would also solve your next issue of "how can I efficiently get all versions of type 'ver'?"

Answer (score 4):

While it's possible to fetch and do the sorting in the client side, you can also use the [Substr](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#substr) function to do this at the server side.

```
from django.db.models.functions import Substr

MyTable.objects.all().order_by(Substr('my_char_field',3))
```

Update:

I was working on another update to the answer, when the question was updated yet again!! The following is not complete, but you can build on it.

```
MyTable.objects.annotate(
    sort_field=Case(
        When(my_char_field__start_with='ver', Then=Substr(my_char_field, 3)),
        When(my_char_field__start_with='x', Then=Substr(my_char_field, 1)),
        default=my_char_field,
    )

).order_by('sort_field')
```

You will need to use the Cast function as well to cast the sort_field to int. This is going to be one long query!!

Comment: I am sure you didn't look at the updated post? And, this won't work for `10` because it is string.

Comment: I wrote this answer without seeing the update. Guess I will have to add an update.

Comment: @Sayse too many edits to the question, but the new update should get the OP on the track

Comment: @AKS too many edits to the question, but the new update should get the OP on the track

Comment: Yes there are too many updates and the answer you provided is not applicable in general because if tomorrow there is a version `z1.1` you will have to add that as well.

Comment: yes @aks in that sense, the newly added answer is the right one

Comment: Small typo on the last line (missing closing quote), but I'd imagine this is the only possible way to make such a query +1 (Not entirely sure it would produce the correct order atm since it looks like it would do ver3, x5.., ver 10 but I'm sure op has a good starting point here)

Comment: yeah @Sayse, needs a lot of work. your answer is definitely the right one and I upvoted, the OP should accept yours as correct.

Answer (score 1):

I have a CharField with a name field, which has mixed (int+string) values, for example. "a1", "f65", "P", "55" e.t.c ..

Solved the issue by using the sql cast (tested with postgres & mysql),
first, I try to sort by the casted integer value, and then by the original value of the name field.

```
parking_slots = ParkingSlot.objects.all().extra(
        select={'num_from_name': 'CAST(name AS INTEGER)'}
    ).order_by('num_from_name', 'name')
```

This way, in any case, the correct sorting works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just as @AKS mentioned, It could be inefficient to do the sorting in memory. As soon as you have a large table and you want to pull only the first page of results sorted.  Then you have to pull every single row from the database before you can do the sort.

---

Maybe you could try to add another field which populate from the "sorting" field when you add a new record. This time, you could make the database sorting works for you.

`Something From Vem3456 to  Vem6543`